# Documentation of xhprof php profiler needed

Tags: php, profiler, graphviz, graph-visualization, xhprof

The last days I was trying to install and run the xhprof.
I finally made it and I think that it brings up very interesting information. I also installed graphviz and I can generate nice graphs, but I would like to find a documentation explaining what the colors in the graphs mean? What does exactly mean each column of the profiler report and how is it calculated.

I was trying to find something the whole day, but unfortunately the only information that I found were usage documentation.

Does any of you have such documentation or know a link? 
[This link](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html) seems to be broken...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is still available via [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514095512/http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html).

I've filed [an issue with facebook](https://developers.connect.facebook.com/bugs/405216349519996/) about it already.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this site:
[http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/](http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/)
it contains all required basic information needed for digging deeper into XHProf.

you will also find windows builds here: [www.phpfluesterer.de](http://www.phpfluesterer.de)

Comment: Yes and it was very helpful indeed, but I was/am searching for more information about the report than what this article provides.